# Editing a file via sftp with user as root and ssh based authentication gives IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied errors

Tags: python, sftp, paramiko

I am encountering IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied error when I try to edit a file with user root while using SSH based authentication. What am I doing wrong?

```
try:
  ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
  ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
  ssh.connect(hostname, username=userName, key_filename=keyFile)
  print "Connection succesfully established ... "
except paramiko.AuthenticationException,e:
  print "Could not connect to %s" % hostname

def changepwd():
  sftp_client = ssh.open_sftp()
  fname = '/etc/ssh/sshd_config'
  with sftp_client.open(fname, 'r+') as f:
    data = f.read()
    f.seek(0)
    f.write(re.sub(r'PasswordAuthentication no', 'PasswordAuthentication yes', data))
    f.close()
  os.system("service sshd restart")
  sftp_client.close()
  ssh.close()
```

Error:

```
    with sftp_client.open(fname, 'r+') as f:
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paramiko/sftp_client.py", line 372, in open
    t, msg = self._request(CMD_OPEN, filename, imode, attrblock)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paramiko/sftp_client.py", line 813, in _request
    return self._read_response(num)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paramiko/sftp_client.py", line 865, in _read_response
    self._convert_status(msg)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paramiko/sftp_client.py", line 896, in _convert_status
    raise IOError(errno.EACCES, text)
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied
```

Comment: Just to be sure, check who you are: `os.system("whoami")`

Comment: @Chocorean Thanks, os.system("whoami") ->  'Executing as root'

Comment: Well, you should probably investigate around `ssh.open_sftp()`

Comment: If you login to your SFTP server using any SFTP client using the same credentials, can you edit the file?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for the responses. I ended up using exec_command directly, which works fine.

```
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command("sed -i -e 's/PasswordAuthentication no/PasswordAuthentication yes/' /etc/ssh/sshd_config")
```